# pip launcher fatal error due to change in user name

Tags: python, pip

previously i had changed the name of my user folder name and after doing so when i tried using pip to install packages for my virtual environment it started showing error

how do i resolve this issue

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\paul lhungdim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\paullhungdim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" '

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would likely be just uninstalling and reinstalling pip. Since this is a Microsoft product, you may need to go through the files and registry to ensure it cleans out all the old data and paths before reinstalling. But I would do that only if a regular uninstall and reinstall doesn't work.

You can also manually check the paths used by things. In windows see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows) as an example.