# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process python.exe

Tags: python, pip

[My CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4QYg.png)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22622.450]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MosMotov>where python
C:\Users\MosMotov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
C:\Users\MosMotov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\MosMotov>where pip
C:\Users\MosMotov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\MosMotov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe

C:\Users\MosMotov>pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\MosMo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Users\MosMotov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can someone help me fix this please?
I already set my PATH in environment variable to User MosMotov and i use where python and where pip to see where are them but when i run pip it still run in User MosMo and error

Comment: Not the best possible solution but **should** work: Find a hex editor which allows to insert and delete bytes into/from a file ( http://www.pspad.com/ contains such an editor). Open `pip.exe` in this editor. Near the end there is a block (after a lot of null bytes) beginning with the path to the Python executable. Change it to the right one and save the file. Make a backup of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip launcher fatal error due to change in user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363276/pip-launcher-fatal-error-due-to-change-in-user-name)

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall your python and just simply install it again.